# Selecting Record based on latest date

Tags: ms-access

I have a query that returns the following information

```
StockCode   BomReference    MaxOfMaxOfDATE

2112003       5109200        17/06/2014
2112003       5112272        02/05/2014
2112113       5112113        11/06/2014
2112113       5113039        22/04/2014
2112120       5112120        20/03/2014
2112120       5113035        30/05/2014
2112140       5109191        13/06/2014
2112140       5112140        30/04/2014
2112140       5113024        01/04/2014
2112141       5109193        13/06/2014
2112142       5109192        13/06/2014
2112143       5112311        15/05/2014
2112143       5112344        07/06/2014
2112146       5112341        16/04/2014
2112154       5112154        16/06/2014
2112154       5113036        07/05/2014
```

I want to be able to select the StockCode and bom reference which has the latest date;

So the results i would like are

```
StockCode   BomReference    MaxOfMaxOfDATE

2112003       5109200        17/06/2014
2112113       5112113        11/06/2014
2112120       5113035        30/05/2014
2112140       5109191        13/06/2014
2112141       5109193        13/06/2014
2112142       5109192        13/06/2014
2112143       5112344        07/06/2014
2112146       5112341        16/04/2014
2112154       5112154        16/06/2014
```

Any advise would be very helpful.

Comment: Take a look at aggregate queries (use a `GROUP BY` clause)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT
    G.StockCode
,   Y.BomReference
,   G.MaxDate
FROM
    [YourQuery] AS Y
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT StockCode, MAX(MaxOfMaxOfDATE) AS MaxDate 
FROM [YourQuery]
GROUP BY StockCode
) AS G
ON Y.StockCode = G.StockCode
AND Y.MaxOfMaxOfDATE = G.MaxDate
```

Comment: This just returns all the records from the initial query.

Comment: I think what you want is the latest date per StockCode, not per StockCode and BomReference. And then for that StockCode and Date, show the matching BomReference. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes it is. I want to show the latest date for the stock code and the associated bomreference.

Comment: Works a treat. Thanks for your help.